# Primary key with two columns in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, foreign-keys, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I have tables with emp1 and emp2

emp1:

```
emp_1 | emp_2
1     | 2
3     | 4
5     | 6
```

emp2:

```
emp
1
2
3
6
```

I tried to set primary key to table emp1 and foreign key to emp2.

My code:

For primary key:

```
alter table emp1 add primary key(emp_1,emp_2);
```

For foreign key:

```
alter table emp2
add foreign key (emp)
references a_t1(emp_1,emp_2);
```

Error:

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-02256: number of referencing columns must match referenced       columns
02256. 00000 -  "number of referencing columns must match referenced columns"
*Cause:    The number of columns in the foreign-key referencing list is not
       equal to the number of columns in the referenced list.
*Action:   Make sure that the referencing columns match the referenced
       columns.
```

Kindly help me to solve this error and set the primary key.

Comment: You are trying to add a foreign key from one field to two fields; you have to decide whether the values in the table EMP2 must match the records in the column emp_1 OR emp_2 from the table EMP1.

Comment: You can't have an FK refer to part of a composite PK, or either of two separate keys (PK or UK). What would you expect to happen if, say, you had rows in emp1 with values (7,8) and values (8,9), and wanted a row in emp2 with value (8)? Which row in the parent would that be referring to?

Comment: yeh I got it. I was trying to make a composite primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think to do it is a nasty hack involving a materialized view. It would be better to fix your data so that you don't have the primary key spread across two columns.

```
CREATE TABLE EMP1 (
  EMP_1 INT UNIQUE,
  EMP_2 INT UNIQUE,
  PRIMARY KEY ( EMP_1,EMP_2 )
);

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON EMP1
   WITH SEQUENCE, ROWID(EMP_1, EMP_2)
   INCLUDING NEW VALUES;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW EMP1_MV
   BUILD IMMEDIATE
   REFRESH FAST ON COMMIT
   AS SELECT EMP_1 AS EMP
      FROM   EMP1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT EMP_2
      FROM   EMP1;

ALTER TABLE EMP1_MV ADD CONSTRAINT EMP1_MV__PK PRIMARY KEY ( EMP );

CREATE TABLE EMP2 (
  EMP INT PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES EMP1_MV( EMP )
);
```

Comment: Thank U. I got the concept. I will try with materialised view .